# Why does this only output the first letter of the string I enter?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function prototypes */
void wordLength ( char *word );

int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    char word [20];

    printf( "Choose a function by enterting the corresponding number: \n"
        "1) Determine if words are identical\n"
        "2) Count number of words in sentence provided\n"
        "3) Enter two strings to be strung together\n"
        "4) Quit program\n" );
    scanf( "%d", &choice );
    flushall();

    while (choice >= 1 && choice < 4) 
    {
        /* if statements for appropriate user prompt and calls function */
        if (choice == 1) 
        {
            /* gather user input */
        printf( "\nYou have chosen to determine word length.\n"
                "Please enter the word:\t");
            gets( word );

            /* call function to output string as well as the string length */
            wordLength( word );

        }
    }
}

void wordLength( char *word )
{
    printf( "The string entered is:  %c\n", *word);
}
```

Whenever I input a word my program only outputs the first letter of the string. Why does it do this? My string length is declared as 20 so I know that it isn't the problem! I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Please forget that the function `gets()` exists.  Pretend it blows your computer up when you use it.  It is a major security liability.  Use `fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin)`, but be aware that it includes the newline at the end of the line (but doesn't overflow your string).  You should also check that `fgets()` got some input before using it (and if you persist in using `gets()`, you should check that, too). You should check your `scanf()` call: `if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1) ...oops...`. Note that `scanf()` leaves a newline behind for `gets()` to read on the first time through the loop.

Comment: `gets` is also no longer part of the standard library; it was deprecated in C99 and removed completely in C2011.

Answer (score 6):

Because you told it to print one character:

```
printf("The string entered is: %c\n", *word);
```

If you want the string, use:

```
printf("The string entered is: %s\n", word);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void wordLength( char *word )
{
    printf( "The string entered is:  %c\n", *word);
}
```

In your `wordLength` function you are using `%c` as your format specifier.  `%c` is used to print one character.  Use `%s` to print a string.

Also change *word to word.  *word references the first or "zeroeth" value in the array - a single character.

The parameter "word" without the asterisk references the entire array which can also be represented as &word[0].  That means it's the address of the zeroeth element.

To summarize...
%s expects an address of an array, & specifies address and the [0] specifies the zeroeth element.  A variable without the & and corresponding array brackets [] is equivalent.  So "&word[0]" is the same as just "word".  This might seem pointless until the day you need to specify the address of an element that's not the zeroeth element such as &word[10].  For example if your string is "Sit on a potato pan Otis" and you want to pull out the word "Otis" from the string.

%c expects a single character, the asterisk "de-references" a pointer, so *word references the actual character, not the address of the character.

To visualize it, picture a pillbox, the kind used by perhaps your grandfather for his medicine.  The pillbox represents an array of characters.  There are 7 little compartments, each one labeled for each day of the week starting with Sunday and ending with Saturday.  So your array goes from 0 to 6.  The first compartment is the beginning of the string.  Sunday is the address of the zeroeth element of the array of characters.

When you open the Sunday compartment you get to the pills inside - this is the "value".  Sunday would be represented as &word[0], Monday would be &word[1].  If you want the value - the pills - inside the Sunday compartment then you specify *word.  If you want the whole array as a string (to feed the %s format specifier), then you can specify either &word[0] or just plain "word" because they are equivalent.  If you wanted to print the string starting from the second character, you would specify &word[1].  Want the value inside the Monday compartment?  Use *(word+1) and for a character use %c to print it.  I hope I have clarified things for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using %c as a modifier, which only prints characters. You should use %s. Check out [println modifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 0):

You can print character by character if you have to use it, by using this:

```
for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ ){
    printf( "%c", *( word + i ) );

    /* If you reach the end of the string, print a new line and stop. */
    if( *( word + i ) == '\0' ){
       printf( "\n" );
       break;
    }
}
```